# Is apache netbeans 11.3 compatible jdk 13 does jdk 13 include derby database?

Tags: java, derby, netbeans-11

I had installed Apache NetBeans 11.2 whereas my JDK was 13. I was facing lots of issues such as in my java ant web project if I run a simple java code to print hello it would show virtual machine not found error whereas the same program would run without any issue in a normal java ant project. So I was wondering is this some compatibility issue?
Also, I find derby useful for my small project but it was not included in jdk13 as in its previous versions.

Comment: Is your question: "Is Derby included in JDK 13"?

Answer (score 0):

JavaDB was removed in Java 8 update 181.  JavaDB is no longer shipped with Java Runtime Environment.